# Google signin button in react only calls success function on page reload

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I've started playing with react and now want to create a google signin for my app.

I have registered my application with google and allowed my localhost:3000 for this app.

According to what I have found in the google documentation I have created a component to render the button and handle the callback.
But when I sign in using my account, the text on the button changes to "Signed In" but the success callback is not executed.
When I then refresh the page, the callback is called.

Has anybody faced a similar problem before?

Here is the code for my component

```
onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}

handleFail(error){
    console.log('login failed');
}

componentDidMount() {
    gapi.signin2.render('g-signin2', {
        scope: 'profile email',
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
        longtitle: true,
        theme: 'dark',
        onsuccess: this.onSignIn,
        onfailure: this.handleFail
    });

    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init();
      });
}

render() {
    return ( 
        <div id="g-signin2" className="g-signin2" />
    );
}
```

Comment: this.setState() will  trigger re rendering of the component, try to add this.state={loaded: false} and set it to true once you logged in with setState

Comment: Hi Max
Thank you for the response. However, to be able to set it to true I have to know if the user is logged in. This is where the problem is, the callback isn't called the first time so I will have no trigger to set the state

Comment: which npm pkg are you using for google-login?

Comment: no npm package, I am trying to do it like stated in the google docs.

Comment: from my understanding of what is going on gapi.auth2  works with DOM and React doesn't, thats because React works with ReactDOM, easiest way to start working with gagi.auth2  is to use this :[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login). I tried it and it worked like a charm

Comment: also look into this [react and DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). I hope I helped you :)

Comment: Thank you max, got it working with the npm package you provided.